# Regex to validate an alphanumeric consecutive string

Tags: regex

I'm looking to have a regex that validates any string from 046R to 120R.

Sounds simple enough, but I'm missing something here.
this is what I have:

```
^04[6-9]R|0[5-9][0-9]R|10[0-9]R|11[0-9]R|120R +$
```

But it's not picking up the 120R as a valid string as well. As can this expression be simplified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have ` +` (only) after 120R? It means that when you have 120R, it has to be followed by at least one space.

Comment: `10[0-9]R|11[0-9]R` ~ `1[01][0-9]R`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the final  `+`. Otherwise it requires one or more space after the string `120R` to be validated.

Also, `|` has very low precedence. The `^` and `$` should stay outside of the group containing `|`.

```
^(?:04[6-9]|0[5-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9]|120)R\s*$
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  One more thing, though - if you _do_ want to allow trailing spaces, you can use `*` (zero or more) instead of `+` (one or more): `^(...)R *$`  Cheers!

Comment: That's not working out. It doesn't accept some of the values that it should. Have a look: [link]http://www.rubular.com/r/YZsPIRInNV

Comment: @Bruno: That's because your test case is not "clean" — some entries contains unnecessary trailing space. This can be fixed by adding a `\s*` at the end like Xavier's comment. See http://www.rubular.com/r/3prIDsOncr

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude certain matches by using negative lookahead, and simplify the regex.

```
^(?!0[0-3])(?!04[0-5])[01]\d\dR$
```